# Graphics2d and Jpanel

Tags: jpanel, graphics2d

I have JFrame with some components and JPanel where will be graphic objects.
I'm trying to add Line on JPanel

```
DrawingPanel()
{
    DrawCellsComponent drawCellsComponent = new DrawCellsComponent();
    add(drawCellsComponent);
}
```

And here is code of component.

```
public void paintConponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 250, 250));
}
```

There isn't any Line on JPanel. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Just draw in JPanel not in JComponent